# Removing column names in pandoc table - r markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

Is it possible to remove (not to show) column names in pandoc tables?
If I use `pander` (or `pandoc.table`) function it prints column names automatically.

```
> pander(iris[1:4, ])

-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sepal.Length   Sepal.Width   Petal.Length   Petal.Width   Species 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
 5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

 4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

 4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  

 4.6            3.1           1.5            0.2       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expected output should be:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 &nbsp;         &nbsp;        &nbsp;        &nbsp;         &nbsp; 
-------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- ---------
 5.1            3.5           1.4            0.2       setosa  

 4.9             3            1.4            0.2       setosa  

 4.7            3.2           1.3            0.2       setosa  

 4.6            3.1           1.5            0.2       setosa  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this suffice?

```
pandoc.table({temp <- iris; names(temp) <- rep(" ", ncol(temp)); temp[1:4,]})
```

to yield.

```
----------------------

--- --- --- --- ------
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa
4.9  3  1.4 0.2 setosa
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
----------------------
```

Comment: or use `temp <- iris; names(temp) <- rep("&nbsp;", ncol(temp)); temp[1:4,]}` to get the exact desired content given.

Answer (score 4):

I'd fix this outside of `pander` by simply removing the column headers:

```
> df <- iris[1:4, ]
> names(df) <- NULL
> pander(df)

--- --- --- --- ------
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 setosa

4.9  3  1.4 0.2 setosa

4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 setosa

4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 setosa
--- --- --- --- ------
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace Benjamin's &nbsp with NULL but otherwise agree:

```
temp <- iris[1:4,]; names(temp) <- rep(NULL, ncol(temp)); temp[1:4,] 
pandoc.table(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

setting column names to `NULL` like so `names(dt) <- NULL` actually gives an error. In my case

`Error in alloc.col(newx) : 
  Internal error: length of names (0) is not length of dt (2)`

using a `data.table` with 2 columns.

Instead, I'd go with

`names(dt) <- rep(" ", ncol(dt))
pander(dt)`